calculate mean for each ip have average
def calculate_mean(IP_Average):
    IP_Average_numbers = []
    for x in IP_Average:
        try:
            if x != '':
                value = float(x)
                IP_Average_numbers.append(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass  # Skip non-numeric values

    if IP_Average_numbers:
        mean = sum(IP_Average_numbers) / len(IP_Average_numbers)
        return mean
    else:
        return None  # Return None if no valid values are found

did this code calculate mean for ips in ping

You should write a clear question, the coding part is ok (even if it's not formatted), but what is your problem? Is the code showing an error? If so please show us. Which kind of data do you have? I don't understand what you need

From what I noticed, you are trying to return a value outside function body. That's why it breaks. Here the refactored code below, with function body and returns intended value also has edge cases covered such as handling string values
Try this code below:
IP_Average_numbers = [1, 3, 5] # This is an example test values
formatted_arr = []

def get_mean(arr) -> float: 
  if len(IP_Average_numbers) > 0:
    for num in IP_Average_numbers:
      if not isinstance(num, str):
        formatted_arr.append(float(num))  
    return sum(formatted_arr) / len(formatted_arr)
  else:
    return None

print(get_mean(IP_Average_numbers))


